# Error al obtener y enviar imagenes con nodejs y angularjs

Tags: angularjs, nodejs

He realizado un web service que permite obtener múltiples imágenes para poderlas guardar en mi base de datos, en si la estructura que nodejs debe recibir es la siguiente

```
{"archivo": variable_files}.
```

Para que mi servidor guarde la información utilizo la librería formidable, Hasta allí todo bien cuando hago pruebas con POSTMAN en mi servidor recibo la data como lo siguiente [image: imagen 1],

Pero cuando envío desde mi frontend con angularjs la data:

```
 $scope.data = {};

    $scope.uploadFiles = function (files) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            $scope.data = ({"archivo": files});
            Upload.upload({
                url: CONFIG.api_url+'images/13',
                method: 'POST',
                data: $scope.data
            }).then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                alert(response.data.error.error_data)
                Notification.error("Error");
            }, function (evt) {
                $scope.progress = 
                    Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }
    };
```

mi servidor me imprime lo siguiente [image: imagen2]
si se dan cuenta la segunda imagen es diferente a la primera, quisiera saber como soluciono este problema, de antemano les agradezco

Comment: ¿Podrías poner la salida como texto y explicar qué es lo que te falla o no te cuadra? Las imágenes no se ven bien y no veo a qué te refieres

Comment: Hola gracias por contestar, la estructura de la primera imagen es: "{archivo:[File:{]}" y el de la segunda img es: "{archivo[0]:File{}}" la idea es que la estructura de la segunda img se transforme en el de la primera.

Comment: Entonces falta el código de *front-end*: Es desde ahí desde donde se manda la información y donde tienes que solucionar el problema